Pyinstaller isn't properly converting a python script with alot of dependencies to an exe file
I have written a python script that enables users to upload pdf files and ask questions about them. The script uses Gemini for smart responses and PyQt5 for the GUI. I am trying to convert this script into an executable file that is portable and can run on other windows devices. The script has the following imports:
import sys
import os
import re
import google.generativeai as genai
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, 
                             QTextEdit, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QWidget, 
                             QMessageBox, QInputDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from langchain.text_splitter import MarkdownTextSplitter
import fitz

I tried pyinstaller but after a long period converting the script to exe, the exe file didn't work and kept showing this error fatal error: failed to extract .... decompression resulted in return code -1. I think the problem might be with the hidden imports but I couldn't solve it.
